# The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0

Tags: react-native, gradle, maven-central

When I sync my react native project in android studio I got those warnings

```
The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0.
```

I got those warnings for multiple libraries like

```
@react-native-community\masked-view
react-native-firebase_app
react-native-firebase_auth
```

Although I replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` in my main `gradle`.
So My question is that How I replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` in all my node modules libraries because I Think it's not a right way to just go in all libraries one by one and replace. Currently I am using gradle 7.0.2